# Is a $\sigma$-algebra closed under countable applications of intersection and union (not just countable intersection/countable union)?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, set-theory

I'm just learning about $\sigma$-algebras and measure theory, so I hope this question is well-defined. I know that a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under countable union, countable intersection, and relative complements. What I'm wondering is whether it is closed under countable applications of these operations? In particular, if we are talking about a $\sigma$-algebra generated by a certain collection of sets, say $\{A_{\alpha}\}$, can any set in this $\sigma$-algebra be represented using finitely many applications of these operations on elements of the generating set or is it possible that some elements cannot be so represented? Can there be elements of the form $(\cup \cap \cup \cap \cup \cap ... ) A_{\alpha}$ where the number of unions and intersections we're taking is countably infinite? In my head, I'm comparing this to, for example, the Free Group on a certain number of elements. Even though we can have elements in the Free Group of arbitrary length, any particular element is still only some finite combination of the generators, e. g., if we're talking about the Free Group on a single element, $a$, the elements are all of the form $a^k$ where $k$ is some integer, but there's no "infinite" element, i.e. $a^{\infty}$ doesn't make sense/isn't an element of the Free Group generated by the element $a$. Likewise, a vector space can have an infinite basis but any particular element of a vector space is a linear combination of finitely many basis elements. Going back to the question about a $\sigma$-algebra, in particular, can any Borel set be represented using only finitely many applications of union, intersection, and complement on the closed sets? For example, I know that there are $F_{\sigma}$ sets, and I think it makes sense to talk about $F_{\sigma \delta}$ sets, $F_{\sigma \delta \sigma}$, etc., but does it make sense to talk about $F_{\sigma \delta \sigma ...}$ where this process of taking unions and intersections is infinite? Would such an element be considered a Borel set? Any insight would be appreciated! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, there can be such elements. You could look for "Borel hierarchy", and you'll see that in fact the process you describe in the end can be indeed countably infinite.

Comment: In fact, if you look at this hierarchy, you'll see that Borel sets are precisely the union of all this sets formed by alternating union and intersection of open and closed sets (countably alternating them).

Comment: Let $S$ be a $\sigma$-algebra. For each $n\in \Bbb N$ suppose $B_n$ is the union or intersection of a countable subset of $S.$ Then each $B_n\in S$. So $C=\{B_n:n\in\Bbb 
 N\}$ is a countable subset of $S$. So $\cup C\in S$ and $\cap C\in S.$